# Notification in iPhone

Tags: iphone, android, objective-c

Can we give notifications(which display for a moment and then disappear), in iPhone, **(like toast in android)**.

If yes, Then How?

If no, then what is the alternative(except alert and action sheet)?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent to Android Toast Notifications in the iPhone SDK (4.3). You have to implement those notifications on your own. The GameCenter framework has a similar capability to show achievements. There is a library to recreate these achievement-notifications without GameCenter:

https://github.com/typeoneerror/GKAchievementNotification

I recommend to read through this code, understand its key concepts and then start developing your own notification system with a custom UIView subclass and a custom notification handler class.